# Stuck at "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" error

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, tuples

I have two lists. Even though the length are the same, the size of them are different. While parameters_train consists of 4 elements in one row, score1 consists of only one.
I am trying to make a function that stores the generalization error. Here's the code and the error.

[image]

To give you an idea here is preview of lists.

[image]

My expected outcome is this.

```
generalization_error= [0, 0, 0.06, and so on...
```

Comment: So your `i` index is a tuple, not integer, as each element in your x is a tuple.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Comment: It does not. Even though the length are the same, the size of them are different. While parameters_train consists of 4 elements in one row, score1 consists of only one.

Answer (score 1):

As each element in your `x` is tuple, when you iterate you get a tuple, not integer, so
you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(x):
    generalization_error.append((x[i][3] - y[i])
```

This will ensure you get the right index. If you also need the actual tuple along with it you can do

```
for i, item in enumerate(x):
    generalization_error.append(item[3] - y[i])
```

You might also need to check your `y[i]` is a legitimate value, as this comes under assumption that for any given `x[i]` there's an existing `y[i]`.

Comment: I used the first code. But I got "unexpected EOF while parsing" this error. When I used the second code I didn't get an error but generalization_error turned up empty.

Comment: You have to check if your lists have same size and you can actually iterate over them, but if they are non empty and you know they have n elements both, you can just use `enumerate`.

Comment: The length of the lists are the same. But parameters_train consists of 4 elements in one row, score1 consists of only one. I used both of the codes you gave but they didn't work. I also updated the question considering the other comments.